# Is it possible to use Firebase multi-factor authentication in an native Ionic/Capacitor app when AppCheck is enabled

Tags: reactjs, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebase-app-check

I am attempting to implement Firebase MFA in my React Ionic application, following the steps outlined in the [official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/multi-factor). While the MFA process works in the web browser, it fails on an iPhone with a 403 error when attempting the initial call to `https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword`. I believe the issue is related to CORS validation with the API, as I am receiving the following error message:

`Firebase: Error (auth/requests-from-referer-capacitor://localhost-are-blocked.).`

In the web implementation, four calls are made over the network, all of which are successful:

- https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:lookup
- https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword
- https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/mfaSignIn:start
- https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v2/accounts/mfaSignIn:finalize

AS mentioned above when testing on an iPhone, only the signInWithPassword endpoint is called and I receive the 403 error.

I have tried to sign in using the Firebase JavaScript SDK and Capacitor plugin, as shown below:

JavaScript SDK:

```
// ...

import { signInWithEmailAndPassword } from "firebase/auth";

// ...

export const signIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
  const credentials = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password).catch((e) => {
    throw e;
  });

  return credentials;
};
```

Capacitor Plugin:

```
// ...

import { FirebaseError } from "firebase/app";
import { signInWithEmailAndPassword, MultiFactorError } from "firebase/auth";
import { Capacitor } from "@capacitor/core";
import { FirebaseAuthentication } from "@capacitor-firebase/authentication";

// ....

export const signIn = async (email: string, password: string) => {
   const response = { result: undefined, verificationId: undefined, resolver: undefined };

  if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform()) {
    try {
      await FirebaseAuthentication.signInWithEmailAndPassword({ email, password });
    } catch (e) {
      // If a second factor is already enrolled, an SMS is automatically sent
      // and the verificationId is returned as the errorMessage
      if (e.code === "auth/multi-factor-auth-required") {
        response.verificationId = e.errorMessage;
      }
    }
  }

  try {
    response.result = await signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password);
  } catch (e) {
    if (Capacitor.isNativePlatform() && e instanceof FirebaseError && e.code === "auth/multi-factor-auth-required") {
      // we get the resolver from the JS error
      response.resolver = getMultiFactorResolver(auth, e as MultiFactorError);
    } else {
      throw e;
    }
  }

  return response;
}
```

Both methods work in the browser, but fail on an iPhone.

I tried using the iOS key (auto created by Firebase) instead of the Browser key (auto created by Firebase), but I receive a similar error:

`Error (auth/requests-from-this-ios-client-application-<empty>-are-blocked.).`